Tag for questions related to Ubuntu EOL
I posted a question about some specifics about Ubuntu EOL at Ubuntu end of life: will snap applications still receive updates?
I wasn't sure how to tag this because it isn't specific to a single Ubuntu version. Is there an appropriate tag for such questions?
I end up creating ubuntu-eol which I probably shouldn't have but hopefully someone can fix it with a more apt name (or remove it). Also, the tag end-of-life exists on meta but not on main but end-of-life can apply to other software as well, not just Ubuntu. Like we could have tag pairs in questions such as 14.04+end-of-life or vlc+end-of-life.

P.S. I don't understand why EOL questions should be offtopic. I got a comment with "Questions about EOL versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here." but this makes no sense.
Use case 1: I have a machine I rarely use with 23.10 which reaches EOL today. I'm waiting for 24.04.1, that is scheduled for release on August 15, for a fresh install. There's no point in spending time upgrading this machine right now because I have a dev environment configured which I might need (although I probably won't) before the point release is available and ugpgrading now could potentially mess something up meaning spending time fixing something which I'll have to redo when 24.04.1 is available anyway.
Use case 2: Some researcher creates a prototype (think science paper) that worked and was tested on a Ubuntu version which is now EOL. If someone else grabs the prototype and has trouble running/testing it on a more recent version of Ubuntu a canonical answer to that from whomever produced it is "I wrote and tested that on Ubuntu 4.04 and you're using Ubuntu 29.04." The one running it all these versions later doesn't necessarily care if the OS is up to date or not, just wants the prototype to work.
I know these are edge cases, but axing everything EOL seems excessive.

Use case 2: in that case, the answer is going to be referring to an EOL release, not the question. Answers don't get tagged. Questions get tagged. So it's fine to ask that without tagging the question "EOL" or something like that (and OTOH wouldn't tagging it "EOL" imply you know it wouldn't be possible to run the software on a supported release before asking?). In that case the question would be: "How do I get X to run on 24.04", and the answer could be "You can't, you need 23.10", or something else. And "You can't, you need 23.10" would be a legitimate answer.

From the release-management tag excerpt (emphasis added):

Questions about the release procedures for a release, including policies, stable release updates, and distribution upgrades.

Use case 1 falls under this. Use case 2 is simply about getting software to run. Whether it was tested on an older version or on some other Linux distro is useful information, but irrelevant for tagging.
